# Numitron clock project

Tags: schematics

I originally was looking into a [Nixie](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/110741/my-first-project-looking-for-a-review-and-comments) clock. I'm scaling back a little and going to try a Numitron clock first. It lacks the high voltage :)

Hows this look for a Numitron clock?

The solenoids are [these](http://www.ebay.com/itm/321342920641). I'm planning on putting the Arduino bootloader on the Atmega and using the USB to program it. (I'm planning on using this to mess around with a bit to learn from).

[image]

Comment: Consider using 'off-page' labels for your buses, it will significantly improve the readability of your schematic.

Comment: What are the solenoids for?

Comment: @Andyaka some kind of hellish bells?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany of course it is how silly of me - 5 solenoid outputs to play the pentatonic scale hitting tubular bells LOL

Comment: @Andyaka - for this http://www.ebay.com/itm/251537852441

Answer (score 1):

The Russian IV-9 Numitron-like displays appear to require 3.5V at around 18mA per segment. That means that to mux 6 of them you'd need \$3.5 \times \sqrt 6\$ = 8.6V at about 350mA per common (17% duty cycle), ignoring drop in the drivers.

That is more than the 7447 can handle, and much, much more than a 74HC238 can handle.

I didn't look at the rest of the circuit. Suggest static drive using a power shift register or 74HC595 + ULN2803 buffers.

Comment: Ugh... I really don't "get" electronics I guess (I'm a programmer by trade). More reading for me now :-/